# Generate only POJOs from OpenAPI definition

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have written an web service definition as an OpenAPI document. The openapi-generator-maven-plugin I'm using always generates a whole project with poms and gradle build scripts, but I only need the pojos and maybe the API client to be generated. It should work equally to JaxB or JaxWS code generators.

So is there a way to tell the plugin to generate the Java-Code only? Maybe there is another plugin which does the job?

Here is my configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/my-api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <modelPackage>com.my.path.to.api</modelPackage>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <generateApis>false</generateApis>
                <generateModels>true</generateModels>
                <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                <library>vertx</library>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
                    <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin

The property you are looking for is:

`generateSupportingFiles`

Set it to **false** if you do not want the additional pom.xml, etc project files generated as well.

Comment: Also it's better to set `<generateApis>false</generateApis>` if you don't need any controllers

Answer (score 0):

In your model project A, allow only model generation.

```xml
<generateApis>false</generateApis>
<configOptions>
  <modelPackage>${default.package.model}</modelPackage>
</configOptions>
```

In your corresponding client/server project B, disable model generation and point the model package name to project A

```xml
<generateModels>false</generateModels>
<configOptions>
  <modelPackage>${default.package.model}</modelPackage>
</configOptions>
```

This is useful when you want to generate multiple server definitions based on different frameworks but want to use the same model underneath.